# Get value of radio button created by Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an Ajax call which generates a group of radio buttons. Now I need to choose a radio button and perform subsequent operations. The radio buttons are correctly displayed, but the radio button choice is not returned.

How do I access the radio buttons generated by the Ajax response?

Main code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>AJAX TEST</title>
<style>
    div{
        margin-left:100px;
    }
    #response{
        padding-top:40px;
    }
    
</style>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
    <h1>Click This Button</h1>
    <button name="button" id="button"  type="button" class="favorite styled"
            type="button">
        Click Here
    </button>
    </div>
    <div id="response" name="response">
        
    </div>
    <div id="radioResponse">
    
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php
    // jquery ajax to show choices
    ?>
    <script>
        $("#button").click(function() {
            console.log('button clicked');
            $.get("ajax1.php", function(data){
                $("#response").append(data);
            });
        });
            $('#radio input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
                var demovalue = $(this).val();
                console.log(demovalue);
                alert("Your result is "+demovalue);
            });
    
    </script>
```

The code for ajax1.php is

```
<?php
$choices =  <<<"CHOICES"
<div id="radio">
    <p><input type="radio" id="a" name="choices"><label for="a">&nbsp;&nbsp;Choice A</label></p>
    <p><input type="radio" id="b" name="choices"><label for="b">&nbsp;&nbsp;Choice B</label></p>
    <p><input type="radio" id="c" name="choices"><label for="c">&nbsp;&nbsp;Choice C</label></p>
</div>
CHOICES;
echo $choices;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event delegation by changing:

```
$('#radio input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
```

To:

```
$('#response').on('change', 'div input[type="radio"]', function(){
```

Please note that for the radio buttons to show a value `.val()` the `input` elements do have to have a `value` attribute with the corresponding value. Example:

```
<input type="radio" id="b" value="B" name="choices">
```

```js
    $('#response').on('change', 'div input[type="radio"]', function(){
        var demovalue = $(this).val();
        console.log(demovalue);
        alert("Your result is "+demovalue);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="response" name="response">
<div id="radio">
    <p><input type="radio" id="a" value="A" name="choices"><label for="a">&nbsp;&nbsp;Choice A</label></p>
    <p><input type="radio" id="b" value="B" name="choices"><label for="b">&nbsp;&nbsp;Choice B</label></p>
    <p><input type="radio" id="c" value="C" name="choices"><label for="c">&nbsp;&nbsp;Choice C</label></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This gets me halfway there. The alert is displayed, but each alert says "Your result is on" instead of "your result is A" or "B" or "C".

Comment: @DougHemingway please add a `value` attribute; see updates above.